# Bilinear forms (Existence of linear operator)

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Can anybody help me in construction of linear operators in exercise 12 of section 10.1, Hoffman and Kunze.

> Let $f,g$ be bilinear forms on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Suppose $g$ is non singular. Show that there exist unique linear operators $S,T$ on $V$ such that $f(a,b)=g(Sa,b)=g(a,Tb)$ for all $a,b$.
>   What if $g$ is singular?

I am not getting how to start.
Any hint will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: For those of us without a copy of Hoffman & Kunzie close at hand: Please provide us with the statement of Exercise 12 of Section 10.1.

Comment: okie, I will edit my ques.

Comment: I added math formatting.  See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) for how to do it yourself next time.  Also, FYI: Standard English punctuation says to put a space after punctuation marks such as `. , ; : ? !`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(e_k)$ be a basis for $V$, and let $A$ and $B$ be the matrices representing $f$ and $g$ relative to this basis; thus (for example)
$$
f(a,b) =\sum_{i,j} a_i A_{ij}b_j,
$$
where $a=\sum_i a_ie_i$ and $b=\sum_{j}b_je_j$. Because $g$ is nonsingular, the matrix $B$ is nonsingular. Let $T$ be the linear operator whose matrix relative to the basis $(e_k)$ is $B^{-1}A$.  I claim that $f(a,b)=g(a,Tb)$ for all $a,b\in V$. To show this is a pretty routine calculation. The uniqueness of $T$ will follow from the nonsingularity of $g$.  The construction of $S$ is similar.

Comment: Will S be A( B inverse) ?

Comment: That $S$ is on the left of $g$ while $T$ is on the right suggests that there's a matrix transpose involved as well. Do the calculation!